# Как получит пользователей с последними комментариями mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Написать SQLзапрос к СУБД MySQL, который выберет из базы имена пользователей и их последние комментарии (по одному комментарию на каждого пользователя), при следующей структуре таблиц:

```
 CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`balance` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE `comments` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`text` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

У меня был вот такой вариант решения, но он немного не подходит. Он выводит пользователей только тех у кого есть комментарий.
Нужно вывести **всех пользователей с их последним комментарием**, при этом если у кого нет коммнента возвращалась строка "нет комментариев"

```
 SELECT uc.name, c.text   
        FROM comments c, ( 
          SELECT u.id, u.name, MAX(c.id) as last_cid   
          FROM users u
          LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.user_id = u.id
          GROUP BY u.id     
        )uc
        WHERE c.user_id = uc.id AND c.id = uc.last_cid";
```

Comment: а почему бы Вам не сделать `left join` к вашему вложенному запросу? т.е. что то типа `select name, text from comments left join (вложенный запрос)`

Comment: Не очень вас понял, не могли бы вы привести полный пример

Comment: посмотрите обновленный вариант запроса, вроде сейчас должно работать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
  u.name,
  c.text
from users u
left join(
  select
    Comments.user_id,
    max(Comments.id) as last_cid,
  from comments
  group by comments.user_id
)uc on u.id=uc.user_id
left join comments c
  on c.id=uc.last_cid
```

т.е. мы выбираем все пользователей, вложенным запросом получаем последние комментарии пользователя, делаем левое внешнее соединение ко вложенному запросу и таким образом получаем то что надо

P.S. замену `null` оставляю сделать Вам. возможно можно улучшить ваш запрос и меня поправят более опытные коллеги

Comment: Запрос выводит ошибку Ошибка SQL (1054): Unknown column 'u.id' in 'field list'

Comment: @Kdes70 опечатка: во вложеннном запросе забыл *алиасы* `commentc` & `users`

Comment: вы были правы в не уверенности max(c.text) , запрос выводит не последний коммент а самый длинный((

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!! все работает верно

Comment: @Kdes70 не за что. рекомендую обратить внимание на на [sql-ex](http://sql-ex.ru/) в свое время мне данный ресурс очень помог